# overriding price model in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am facing problem in overriding product-> type -> price.php  model in Magento.

Here is my `app/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <softweb_catalog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codepool>local</codepool>
    </softweb_catalog>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Here is

```
app/code/local/Softweb/Catalog/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <softweb_catalog>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </softweb_catalog>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <class>Softweb_Catalog_Model</class>
        </catalog>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_price>Softweb_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Now Price.php path is `app/code/local/Softweb/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php`

```
 class Softweb_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
 {

   public function getPrice($product)
   {
      die('function called');
   }

  }
```

I don't know what I am missing....

PS I am using magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: check this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/820/how-to-create-product-price-in-real-time-based-on-forms/821#821) on magento stackexchange looks similar,might help you

Comment: @TejaKorlapati I think it will not but more similar is like this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235679/core-overrides-in-magento although I am checking your link..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem resides here

```
<models>
     <catalog>
          <class>Softweb_Catalog_Model</class>
     </catalog>
....
</models>
```

Here you are defining your model. `catalog` is the reference that you are providing for your module's model. Suppose you have a file `Foo.php` inside your module's model directory. That is

```
Softweb
|
 ----------Catalog
           |
            ----------- etc
           |             |
           |              ---------- config.xml
           |
            ----------- Model
                        |
                         ----------- Foo.php
```

And suppose your `Foo.php` holds a method `Foo()` method.

```
<?php
class Softweb_Catalog_Model_Foo extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
      public function Foo()
      {
           //some foo codes here
           //returns something
      }
}
```

How can you get this `Foo()` method that is defined inside your model? According to your model definition it should look like this

```
 $foo = Mage::getModel('catalog/foo')->Foo();
```

However your **model reference should be unique**. So you cannot use `catalog`  for your model reference. Since it is already using in `Mage_Catalog` core module. See this

```
Location:app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
<global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>catalog_resource</resourceModel>
            </catalog>
            ---------
        </models>
        --------
</global>
```

So if you need to use your model, you should have a unique reference for your model. That is

```
    <models>
        <softweb_catalog>
            <class>Softweb_Catalog_Model</class>
        </softweb_catalog>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_price>Softweb_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
```

Here your module is referenced using `softweb_catalog` and is unique. So now you can access `Foo()`method as like this.

```
  Mage::getModel('softweb_catalog/foo')->Foo();
```

Also it rewrites your required Model file. But since your module does not hold any model files, there is no need for this code. You only need this.

```
<global>
     <models>
       <catalog>
          <rewrite>
             <product_type_price>Softweb_ConstPrice_Model_Price</product_type_price>
          </rewrite>
       </catalog>
     </models>
  </global>
```

It will allow you to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` class. Hope that will help you to understand the fault in your code.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your effort

Comment: I think you understand the mistake. Happy to help you

Comment: Accepting your answer is not a problem. But the actual answer of your question resides in my answer. If you feel I am correct, either you point to my answer by putting a comment on your own answer or accept my answer as right. This is because, poeple who searches for this answer may miss my answer. :)

Comment: Now accepted yours but if someone needs to do it from scratch then my solution will help from then,,, :)

Comment: no one look for entire answer. They will come to this qn when they will trouble with exact same confusion that you have. So this answer make that doubt clear.

Comment: I want to use method **getGroupPrice** from This class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price** 

i did the same thing. some how it's not wotking for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out via this way,

Created `app/etc/Softweb_All.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Softweb_ConstPrice>
  <active>true</active>
  <codePool>local</codePool>
</Softweb_ConstPrice>
```

Then `app/code/local/Softweb/ConstPrice/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
     <Softweb_ConstPrice>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
     </Softweb_ConstPrice>
   </modules>
   <global>
     <models>
       <catalog>
          <rewrite>
             <product_type_price>Softweb_ConstPrice_Model_Price</product_type_price>
          </rewrite>
       </catalog>
     </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Then Price.php under `app/code/local/Softweb/ConstPrice/Model/Price.php`

```
     class Softweb_ConstPrice_Model_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
     {
         public function getPrice($product)
         {
             return 50.00;
         }
     }
```

Don't know why my question Code was not working. :(